# How to cd dir in Vscode teriminal by right click on a target folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the explorer file tree, right click a folder, and in the menu to "cd this folder in terimal". How can I do this?

Comment: right click on folder and there is an option open in integrated terminal click on it

Comment: click open in integrated terminal will start a new shell, how to just cd in this opened teriminal? this may be more convenient, because many environment variables have been loaded in this teriminal.